# Java - implement serializable

Tags: java, interface

Quais os benefícios para o sistema em implementar essa interface em alguma classe java? O que muda em se ter uma classe que implementa em comparação com uma que não tenha a implementação, se baseando que as mesmas tenham os mesmo atributos? E quais seus usos reais?

> Edit

Minha pergunta está relacionada aos benefícios  em se usar essa interface em contra partida de uma classe que não há implementa, fugindo da abordagem de como utilizar o serializable, utilizando exemplos de código.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Serialização é a conversão de um objeto em séries de bytes. Esse objeto pode ser facilmente salvo, persistido em um banco de dados por exemplo ou transmitido de um sistema para outro pela rede, ou até mesmo ser salvo no sistema de arquivos com alguma extensão (conforme o exemplo). Pode ser futuramente "deserealizado" em um objeto. Eu diria "portar" um objeto e seu estado para ao que quiser.

Um caso que eu usei bastante era: Antes mesmo de existir Android, em sistemas J2ME implementava um tipo de objeto de configurações que precisava ser escrito e lido. Ao invés de persistir no banco, dar select, insert etc. simplesmente o objeto era lido, alterada alguma configuração e persistido em um arquivo em um diretório. Essas preferências eram enviadas pela web (objeto serializado) e no sistema web tinham as mesmas preferências. O ponto é a interoperabilidade. Em alguns casos esse é o benefício real.

Aqui está um exemplo referente a este [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/447898/what-is-object-serialization).

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

// This class implements "Serializable" to let the system know
// it's ok to do it. You as programmer are aware of that.
public class SerializationSample implements Serializable {

    // These attributes conform the "value" of the object.

    // These two will be serialized;
    private String aString = "The value of that string";
    private int    someInteger = 0;

    // But this won't since it is marked as transient.
    private transient List<File> unInterestingLongLongList;

    // Main method to test.
    public static void main( String [] args ) throws IOException  { 

        // Create a sample object, that contains the default values.
        SerializationSample instance = new SerializationSample();

        // The "ObjectOutputStream" class have the default 
        // definition to serialize an object.
        ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream( 
                               // By using "FileOutputStream" we will 
                               // Write it to a File in the file system
                               // It could have been a Socket to another 
                               // machine, a database, an in memory array, etc.
                               new FileOutputStream(new File("o.ser")));

        // do the magic  
        oos.writeObject( instance );
        // close the writing.
        oos.close();
    }
}
```

Espero ter ajudado.